# iPhone: in-App Purchase ,Buying once in sandbox

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, mkstorekit

I Have a strange problem with iphone in app purchase!  i created a product in the ituneconnect and then (using MKstorekit) i bought the product in sandbox environment .. and everything went will the first time... i removed the app from the device and created another test account.
and i found in the debugger mode that it sees the product as already purchased !!

tried everything from cleaning the project and all the tricks for the cache problems.. but still the problem occure .. is that normal?? or i'm doing something wrong?

please advice

Comment: Have you logged out from your previous test user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fount the solution..

in app delegate i have to call

```
- (BOOL) removeAllKeychainData
```

in MKStoreManager, call it once at beginning, and then remove it from code, you don't want to accidently leave that on release :S

Answer (score 0):

since you are deleting the app in that case there is no chance that NSUserDefault will be storing this purchase so only thing that comes to my mind is the type of purchase... what type of purchase did you state in itunesconnect consumable , non-consumable or subscription? it could be because you stated subscription as purchase type(subscription purchases can only be bought once)... hope this helps..

this is what I have come across at http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases

---

> StoreKit will prompt the user “are you sure?”, ask them to enter their
>   username/password (if appropriate), make the charge, and send you a
>   success or failure. They’ll also handle the case where the user
>   already paid for the app and is just re-downloading it, and give you a
>   message for that as well.

---

Comment: your edit state the idea of in-app purchase itself.. the problem is that when i create another test user it sees it as if he is the other user and unlock the features that suppose to be locked and never show him the dialog of (are you sure?)

Comment: Have you logged out the first user from your iphone/ipad?